# Need help with limited dataset

Tags: classification

So I have a dataset which is just 400 instances for 4 labels (i.e. 100 examples for each label). Another issue is that each of these instances have 3000x3 features. 
Can anyone tell me which algorithm would be suitable to start with given that features are huge and examples are very few for each class.

Comment: Did you try plotting the datasets first and see what kind of patterns are there if any ?

Comment: @shalini yes I did but they all look 90% similar when plotted. the spread of the points is such that you wont be able to assign a class label to it based on just that plot. My guess is that there are very few features which are differentiating between the 4 classes.